# How To loop the names in C#

Tags: c#

I have 10 text boxes namely TB1, TB2, TB3, TB4 and so on.. to TB10

I want to store them into a single string value named toBeStored.

Now I m doing the manual way

```
String toBeStored=null;
tobeStored=TB1.text.toString();
tobeStored+=TB2.text.toString();
```

and so on..

I want to make a for loop and add them

something like this..

```
for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
{
      toBeStored+=TB+i+.text.ToString()+"  ";
}
```

I know that is wrong.. anything to make it right?

Comment: I select the correct answer as the one which is worked for me..may b the other ones also the correct ones..
Thank you all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Because you defined the text boxes as variables there simply is no enumerator defined.

You could define your own enumerator. In the simpliest case that is as simple as

```
TextBox boxes [] = new TextBox [] { TB1, TB2, TB3....}

foreach (TextBox box in boxes) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I think the premise may be flawed, you could do this by

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
  TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Page.FindControls( "TB" + i.ToString);
  toBeStored += textbox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Well, I just realized I did this for asp.net and you're probably not using asp.net ...

Comment: I think you made a mistake here: Page.FindControls() may not get the control you want if the textbox is put in a PlaceHolder or something.

Comment: @Danny Chen ~ I just went for concept. I don't know enough about how he's doing this to know what will work best. I wanted to demonstrate the .FindControls with the "TB" + i concept. That's all. I agree, this is not bulletproof.

Comment: yea.. i m using C#..and FindControls is giving me error.. any particular thing?

Comment: How are you using FindControls? What style of app are you writing... is this WinForms, ASP.NET? We need a few more details. Post the code you're testing and how it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Put the controls into an array and then iterate the array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't tell us whether you're using winforms, webforms, or what. That would be good.

Second, you probably don't need to use .ToString() on the Text property, which I would assume is already a string.

Finally, if you insist on being lazy, then put the text boxes into an array, and loop over the array:

```
private TextBox[] _textBoxes = new TextBox[10];

// In init code:
TextBox[0] = TB1;
TextBox[1] = TB2;
// ...

StringBuilder toBeStored = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   toBeStored.Append(TextBox[i].Text);
}

// Now process toBeStored.ToString();
```

Comment: ~ How would you go about simplifying the "//In init code:" part? What if there were like 50 textboxes for some unknown reason? Then what would you do?

Comment: I wouldn't simplify it. I might use code generation; I might put the text boxes all inside of a panel or something, iterate through all the controls in the panel, find the text boxes, and then put them all into the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection in general if you want to get a field by name.

```
Type type = GetType();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var name = "TB" + i;
    var field = type.GetField(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); //or appropriate flags
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)field.GetValue(this);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If was to do such a thing I would create a helper method to accumulate the text into a string.

```
    public string AccumulateNames(params string[] names)
    {
        return names.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, name) => current + name);
    }
```

which would be called similar to this

> var toBeStored = AccumulateNames(TB1.Text, TB2.Text, ..., TBn.Text);