# Can anyone give me an example of using C# reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Im just learning about reflection in C#. Anyone know of some good tutorials or want to give me some sample code to look at? Thanks!

Comment: A good sample of what exactly? Reflection is a tool, how about specifying what you'd like to do with it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=c+sharp+reflection+tutorial

Comment: @Jared, agreed -- SO is not an *alternative* to googling...

Comment: There are also plenty of examples [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+reflection+answers%3A1+getmethod+OR+getproperty+OR+getfield) if you search for them.  I have also [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632860/3632964#3632964) [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050458/4802108#4802108) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600569/4610990#4610990) that use reflection.

Comment: @Jared, @Kirk: Nothing wrong with asking on SO before Googling. [This question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions) deals with exactly that issue. The executive summary is that ideally, SO will be the top hit on Google. We don't want a situation where Google sends you to a website that tells you to Google. "Stack Overflow" is intended to be a clever name, not a real phenomenon experienced by users when they try to find information. (Note that I'm not at all disagreeing with the decision to close the question.)

Comment: @Cody - While I understand the sentiment, I (and Jeff M) added my response as a comment, not an answer. If I had added it as an answer, I could see it being a problem (although, it is an "answer", so to speak). As commentary, I believe it is entirely appropriate to point out. There are not too many folks here with the knowledge, talent and communication skills to outdo what is already available online elsewhere; most of them I posit have more constructive things to do here, so these types of questions are bound to become either click farms for Google search results posted as answers, or empty.

Comment: @Jared: I didn't mean to imply that your comment was inappropriate. My last comment was merely informational. There are a lot of users who close questions *just* because they think someone should Google for the answer first. Not only do I disagree with that, but it seems the general consensus is that there's nothing wrong with asking first instead of Googling. I've written many answers, and I've seen others write many, many more, that can and should certainly be the canonical hits for a Google search on that general topic. I'm not really sure what your point was there.

Comment: @Cody - My point merely was, the question as asked is more akin to a forum-type, conversational question, with back and forth, or what you could ask a search engine. I'm guessing that not too many sharp, knowledgeable people here (you included) would go through the trouble of answering *this* question. And the general concept has already been answered here several times: http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=what+is+reflection+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @Cody - Just one other thing: I appreciate your comments. I've wondered about the same things, and what the roles are of those trying to review and answer the questions that we are capable of asking. Asking a question is a simple enough thing, and should not be any more complicated than "is there a legitimate answer?" The more time I spend here, the more refined my approach becomes; I have eaten a shoe on a couple occasions, but those have been useful moments. So, thank you for taking the time to respond with your views. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to look here to start with.. (*Its the first result in Google Search*)

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/